# Unable to create Single Controller from multiple Models - MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, crud

I have two classes called *Company* and *Address*.

I have created a ViewModel for both.

But when I go to the controller and right click to add controller, enter Controller name, Model class as newViewModel and Data context class as dbModel.

It gives me error and is not creating a controller and view for CRUD.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public class nameViewModel
{
    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

Company Table:
CompanyId
Name
Address
Value

Address Table:
AddressId
Address

enter code here
```

Comment: I don't actually use the add controller function to get CRUD generated, but it seems that if you added a controller for Company and a controller for Address, you could then merge the resulting code into one controller.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @NoviceMe: You are going to give a little more detail that just "It gives me an error..". Without some detailed error description makes it hard for us to help.

Comment: @BrendanVogt - I am getting an error saying entity Key is missing.

Comment: @jlnorsworthy - I tried creating crud differently for both but i was not sure how will you combine two controllers to show up in single view? Can you show me some code how that can be done? Thanks!

Comment: @NoviceMe: It's very hard helping you given the amount of code that you share with us. Looking at your code, do you think you can help someone with what is given in the question?

Comment: @NoviceMe: What does the structure of Company and Address look like?

Comment: @BrendanVogt- Sorry i just added Company and Address table, please let me know if i am missing any other info that is needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the questions you are asking, it seems pretty clear that you should start at the beginning and work through a tutorial. I haven't worked through a tutorial since the NerdDinner tutorial for MVC2, but this tutorial seems like a pretty good place to start: [Getting started with ASPNet MVC3](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-3). And in answer to your question about returning "two controllers in one view", a controller (or an action on a controller) is just code that runs in response to a web request. In that action, you would create an instance of your ViewModel (nameViewModel) and return it to a view that expects that viewmodel.